# How to show that if two integral domains are isomorphic, then their corresponding field of quotients are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If two integral domains $D$ and $D'$ are isomorphic show that their corresponding field of quotients (fractions) $Q(D)$ and $Q(D')$ are isomorphic.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are a new user, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("show") to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one approach. Let $\text{Frac}(R)$ denote the fraction field of an integral domain, and for an injective arrow $f:R\to S$ let $\text{Frac}(f)$ be the arrow $\text{Frac}(R)\to\text{Frac}(S)$ defined by $\text{Frac}(f)\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}$. Show that this has the property that $\text{Frac}(g\circ f)=\text{Frac}(g)\circ\text{Frac}(f)$ and that $\text{Frac}(\text{id}_R)=\text{id}_{\text{Frac}(R)}$. Conclude that if $f:R\to S$ is an isomorphism then so is $\text{Frac}(f)$ because $\text{Frac}(f^{-1})$ is an inverse for $\text{Frac}(f)$

This is a general techinque--show that your construction is [functorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor).

If you actually care to learn it, what you have shown is that $\text{Frac}$ is a functor from the category $\mathbf{Dom}$ of integral domains an injective maps to the category $\mathbf{Field}$ of fields and field(ring) maps.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\psi\colon D\to E$ be an isomorphism of integral domains. Let $\iota\colon D\to Q(D)$ be the embedding of $D$ into its field of fractions (via $\iota(a) = \frac{a}{1}$, for instance), and $j\colon E\to Q(E)$ the embedding fo $E$ into its field of fractions (via $j(b)=\frac{b}{1}$).

Then $j\circ\psi\colon D\to Q(E)$ is an injective ring homomorphism (composition of injective ring homomorphisms) that maps $D$ into a field. Therefore, $j\circ\psi$ induces a ring homomorphism $\Psi\colon Q(D)\to Q(E)$ such that $\Psi\circ\iota = j\circ\psi$.

Symmetrically, $\iota\circ\psi^{-1}\colon E\to Q(D)$ is an injective ring homomorphism from $E$ into a field, hence it induces a unique ring homomorphism $\Phi\colon Q(E)\to Q(D)$ such that $\Phi\circ j = \iota\circ\psi^{-1}$.

The map $D\to Q(D)$ given by $\iota$ should induce the identity map on $Q(D)$; that is, the only map $f\colon Q(D)\to Q(D)$ such that $f\circ\iota = \iota$ is $f=\mathrm{id}_{Q(D)}$, by the uniqueness clause of the universal property of $Q(D)$. Since
Now, 
$$\Phi\circ\Psi\circ\iota = \Phi\circ j \circ\psi = \iota\circ\psi^{-1}\circ\psi = \iota = \mathrm{id}_{Q(D)}\circ\iota,$$
it follows that $\Phi\circ\Psi = \mathrm{id}_{Q(D)}$. A symmetric argument using the universal property of $Q(E)$ and $\Psi\circ\Phi\circ j$ shows that $\Psi\circ\Phi=\mathrm{id}_{Q(E)}$.

Therefore, $\Psi$ and $\Phi$ are inverses of each other, hence they are both isomorphisms, showing that $Q(D)\cong Q(E)$.

Note the use of the universal properties, as opposed to an "element-by-element" check; although I specified the definitions of $\iota$ and $j$, those do not need to be specified: all that matters is that they are part of the "universal property" definition.

Comment: Couold you please explqin something to me? How does$j\circ\psi$ induce a ring homomorphism $\Psi\colon Q(D)\to Q(E)$? Specifically what does $\Psi$ to do elements not in the image of $\iota$ ?

Comment: Nice answer, definitely better than a "element-by-element" check. @Bysshed $j\circ \psi$ induces a ring homomorphism by the universal property of the field of fractions. More exactly $\Psi(a/b)=j(\psi(a))j(\psi(b))^{-1}$.